# Does Telegram API allow search user by Peer ID?

Tags: telegram, mtproto

How do I make use of Telegram API (not Telegram Bot API)'s functions? I read from the official [API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser) that there is a function named `users.getFullUser`.

How can I make use of this function to achieve my goal?

Some said I need to use raw command via `MTProto`, but I have no clue where to start? Is there any wrapper in PHP / Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Madeline Proto (docs.madelineproto.xyz) for PHP and Pyrogram for Python.

Comment: This is just another MTProto implementation, but how to search user by Peer ID?